# How do I setup a local webserver that my home PCs can all access?

Tags: iis, server, webserver

I have a PC I'll call Computer A. This is my normal PC (running win10) that I use for browsing the internet, games, homework, etc. I have another PC I'll call Computer B (also running Win10). I have 5 total computers connected to my home network, I want to use Computer B as a webserver that all of those computers can connect to, I'm VERY new to this, how would I start this project? I've tried XAMPP but that only works on Computer B.

Comment: This is a very broad question. What are you trying to share between the computers?

Comment: Eh. Not sure why is this connected with php and html. But you'll need to set-up a router with a dhcp server. Make sure your PC-B will always have the same private IP address the rest can be dynamic. With that, the rest can access with PC-B's private ip address, unless you need to allow some further rules on your router.

Comment: This has nothing to do with, php, html, iis or webserver. It mainly depends on your local network, router, opened ports etc.

Comment: Posting this as a comment instead of an answer because it's not specific enough: I ***think*** XAMPP has a setting somewhere that allows it to be accessed from other machines, where the default is set to `localhost` only. Computer B should have a hostname you can use, but if you can't find that, try connecting to `http://1.2.3.4` where you need to replace `1.2.3.4` with Computer B's internal network IP address. You may also need to mess with Windows 10's firewall settings on Computer B to allow other computers to connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having a linux box would be more common but windows works too.

You may check xxamp again but make sure your router blocks traffic to your home network.

You may open port 80 in PC-B (windows firewall) to allow http connections from computer A to B and for other PCs in your local network.

Then check this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrA_yN3gySs